# What is the anti-derivative of $5xe^{x^2}$??

Tags: integration

I know the anti-derivative of $5e^x$  is  $5e^x$. So, how about $5xe^{x^2}$? Is that gonna be the same?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: Let $u=x^2$. Perform the substitution and get your anti-derivative. Don't forget the $+C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $\frac 5 2 e^{x^{2}}+C$. Just differentiate $\frac 5 2 e^{x^{2}}$ to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e^{x^2}=u$

$\implies \frac {du} {dx} =2xe^{x^2}$

$dx=\frac {du} {2xe^{x^2}}$

So, $\int 5xe^{x^2} dx = \frac {5} {2} \int du$

$=\frac {5u} {2} + C$

$= \frac {5e^{x^2}} {2} +C$